# Salesforce Marketing cloud Journey builder : Need to send real-time email when user enter in a journey for many consumers

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

As per the requirement, I need to send real-time email to user (large audience) when he/she enters in a journey.

I can do it using "API Event" .
But my question is what if there are thousands of users who registers at same time (Like black Friday sale). In this case , Is the api Event is the right choice to go with it? Journey will work in this case?

Is there any other option I use to send real time emails (1:1 communication) to large number of subscribers same time?

Comment: I don’t understand your use case. Normally Journey Builder is either used for real time 1:1 communication (e.g. post registration welcome flow) or a limited number of contacts in batches (e.g. reactivation journey x months after last purchase)

Comment: Yes. I journey builder is used to send 1:1 communication . I wanted to ask is there any any drawback or risk when let say 2000 or more customers are entered in a journey at same time .<br> So in that case is journey builder will deliver the emails to these customer on time or there would be any performance issue. <br> I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that the API entry event cannot inject multiple contacts in a single call, so for 2000 contacts you will need to perform 2000 API calls.

From performance perspective, these are quite low volumes. JB can easily process up to 500.000 contacts/hr/Tenant. This and other limitations and best practices can be found in [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320344&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: Thanks Lucas. It clarified my doubts.

Comment: You are welcome, @vikramChandane. Remember to mark answer as accepted for the benefit of others, and upvote if you find it helpful.